# Reading physical drives in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

In the code given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/disk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/disk0", O_RDONLY, 0);

    ...
}
```

`fd` has `-1` for physical hard drives but it works fine for a USB/flash drive. Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Opening the disk for read-only access is probably only a means to an end - could you use the object-oriented Cocoa APIs instead, to accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a permissions issue. Giving ordinary users any access to raw disks is a security hole (the user could circumvent all file permissions and read anything they want on the disk), so no OS gives raw disk access to normal users.

In the example below, `disk0` is my internal hard drive and `disk3` is a USB flash drive. In OS X, even "administrators" aren't part of the `operator` group that would allow raw disk access to fixed hard drives.

`pip$ ls -ltr /dev/disk*

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   3 Dec 12 10:14 /dev/disk0s3

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   2 Dec 12 10:14 /dev/disk0s2

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   1 Dec 12 10:14 /dev/disk0s1

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   0 Dec 12 10:14 /dev/disk0

br--r-----  1 root  operator   14,   4 Dec 14 15:15 /dev/disk1

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   7 Dec 14 15:15 /dev/disk2s2

br--r-----  1 root  operator   14,   6 Dec 14 15:15 /dev/disk2s1

brw-r-----  1 root  operator   14,   5 Dec 14 15:15 /dev/disk2

brw-r-----  1 pip   operator   14,   9 Dec 14 15:18 /dev/disk3s1

brw-r-----  1 pip   operator   14,   8 Dec 14 15:18 /dev/disk3`

If your app really needs raw disk access you'll either need to run it as root with `sudo`, add yourself to the `operator` group, or use the OS X APIs for privilege escalation.